# Python 2.7, urllib2 and SAML Authentication

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, urllib, saml, saml-2.0

I have a site that has SAML enabled security on it's web services.  How can I use urllib2 to access this site?  Are there any examples showing what I have to do in order to get this to work?

When I access a SAML secure site, should the service url automatically re-direct me to the SAML login site?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question first: yes, when there is an authentication attempt against a SAML secured resource by an unauthenticated user, the site will redirect to the identity provider.

I'm not particularly familiar with SAML secured web services. The magic words to ask the provider of the resource is what SAML Binding is used. The OASIS spec is at https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35389/sstc-saml-profiles-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf See the sequence diagram on page 25 of 69 : the Enhanced Client or Proxy (ECP) Profile would work well for a webservice.